# Are Amazon Elastic Load Balancer (ELB) failure proof?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

The title might be a little too much, but i am unable to find any statements regarding this. I am trying to set up computes in multiple AZ's (in a region) with `auto-scaling`. i am also trying to see if i can get away with only one ELB to do the load balancing act.

In this setup, the ELB is a single point of failure so, I would like to know, if anyone knows the recovery associated with ELB's. There are documentations about scaling in ELB but not the recovery/higher availability.

thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you select multiple AZs for the load balancer as well. You will have to in order for it to work with EC2 instances in multiple AZs anyway. When you do that, multiple ELB instances are created for you behind the scenes, one in each AZ. So the ELB isn't really a "single point of failure".

The most common issue you may see with an ELB is if you have a very quick, large burst of traffic, which will take the ELB a few minutes to scale up to meet the demand. If you know ahead of time you will be getting a large increase in traffic you can send a request to AWS support to pre-warm the ELB for you.

I recommend reading the section titled "*Common Pitfalls When Testing Elastic Load Balancing*" in [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1636185810492479).

Comment: Accepting this as the post included the link to more details about ELB.

Comment: On a different note, to me it doesn't make sense to allow creating rules with other non http/https protocols while setting up a security group for an Application ELB. Its suppose to support only http and https traffic, no??

Comment: Security groups can be attached to multiple things. Maybe you want to use the same group on all your load balancers (ALB, ELB, NLB) or something. Not saying that's a good idea, but security groups are flexible, they don't check if the ports you are opening make sense for what they are currently attached to.

Answer (score 5):

An ELB is a logical entity that consists of multiple (at least 2 - one per AZ - and generally more) instances that route traffic to your back ends.

If an individual ELB instance were to fail, it would be replaced automatically, much in the way autoscaling replaces failed instances.

You can usually tell how many instances are in your ELB by doing a DNS lookup - you will see multiple IP addresses returned.

ELBs can become overloaded if you have a sudden burst of traffic, so they are not failure proof, but for most loads they do a very good job.